# VirtualBox: Unable to access "USB subsystem"

Tags: usb, virtualbox, debian, debian-squeeze

I have a VirtualBox running inside a Debian Squeezy 64 bit machine. For some reason, none of my virtual machines can use the USB ports of the host machine. This error is popping up:

```
Cant load Host USB Proxy service (VERR_FILE_NOT FOUND). 
The service may not be installed on host machine.

Details:
Result code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x0004005)
Component: Host
Interface: IHost {--a big number here--}
Receptor: IMachine {--another big number here--}
```

It would be useful for me to use some USB devices inside my VMs (a USB drive and a printer, for example).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Virtual Box Guest Additions:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

For a howto, see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31726/mount-usb-devices-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu/).

Comment: Guest additions on the HOST machine? (guest additions are installed on every VM)

Comment: @Barranka, I added a link to a howto. You need to install the guest additions package on the host, then install it through VirtualBox, then activate USB controller in the Virtual Machine's settings.

Comment: @terdon I'm still puzzled why you need to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions on the _host_ machine; even the how-to you linked doesn't mention that. I have a problem similar to the OP (with no error popping up though) and installing the Guest Additions package on the host didn't fix it.

Comment: @mguassa See my alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Debian Wheezy, this problem is fixed by adding your user account to the `vboxusers` group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $(whoami) vboxusers
```

You will most likely need to log out and back on for the change to take effect. The `$(whoami)` part will simply be replaced by your username; you can do the replacement manually if you want to, like for example:

```
sudo gpasswd -a barranka vboxusers
```